# Which authentication system to use with Django Rest Framework and Angular and how?

Tags: angularjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

We're building a website using Django + Django Rest Framework for the back and Angular for the front.

There are three authentication systems in django rest (as of [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#api-reference)) :

1. Basic Authentication : "appropriate for testing"
2. Token Authentication : "appropriate for native desktop and mobile app"
3. Session Authentication : "appropriate for Ajax clients"

I'm a bit lost here. I'm guessing session authentication should be the one to use when front is running on Angular. But I'm not sure. And I can't get why token is not appropriate (security issue ?). What if I want to make a mobile app afterwards ? Should I consider two separate parallel authentication system (token for the app, session for Angular) ?

Can someone clarify this to me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirement session authentication would not be feasible.

Token Authentication would be a better choice. If you want more security then you can look into JWT(JSON Web Tokens [link](http://jwt.io/))

Reasons not to choose session authentication for your requirement is perfectly explained [here](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/28/5-steps-to-add-modern-authentication-to-legacy-apps-using-jwts/)

Answer (score 0):

Token authentication should be fine. Session authentication is highly dependent on browsers, the way is implemented. And, for the record, no one stops you from going forward with both - they work just fine. For development phase, you could use sessions to authenticate towards the browsable API.